# Calculating Sick Days in Power Bi

Tags: date, powerbi, measure

How do I calculate sick (working) days between dates in PowerBI?

In excel I had used the NetworkDaysFunction and adding extra columns with the calendar months.

E.g

Person 1
Absence start date
26 - May - 2021

Absence End Date
2 - June - 2021

That should be 3 sick days in May
And 3 in June.

PowerBI in the line graph displays all sick days in May rather than seperate the dates in the months it took place.

How can I only count days between Mon-Fri but also have the sickness in the month they occured?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Calendar table you can try this way:

```
SickDay = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Calendar'), FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), WEEKDAY ('Calendar'[Date]) not in {1,7} && 'Calendar'[Month] = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Month]) && 'Calendar'[Date] >= 'Sick'[DateStart] && 'Calendar'[Date] <= 'Sick'[DateEnd] )
```

WEEKDAY give us 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday